# How to show specific orders in the order grid based on admin user?

Tags: admin, collection, grid, uicomponent, magento2.3.4

I want to show orders which are assigned to the specific admin users.

If any admin user is logged in then orders which are assigned to logged-in admin user will be displayed in an Order grid.

**Note: Admin users are seller which can manage their orders from admin**

How can it be done using UI component?

My Seller Id column Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="import" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import COD AWB</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">ecomexpress/ecomexpress/fetch_fetchawb</item>
            </item>
            <item name="importppd" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">importppd</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import PPD AWB</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">ecomexpress/ecomexpress/fetch_fetchppdawb</item>
            </item>
            <item name="flush" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">flush</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Flush AWB</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">ecomexpress/ecomexpress/deleteawb</item>
            </item>
    </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="ecom_awb_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Ecom\Ecomexpress\Ui\DataProvider\Ecom\AwbDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">awb_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">awb_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="export" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/Export_export</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
         <paging name="listing_paging" />
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="show_ecomexpress_awb_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">show_ecomexpress_awb.show_ecomexpress_awb.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
         <column name="awb_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Awb Id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
         <column name="awb">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Awb</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
         <column name="shipment_to">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship to</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
<!--          <column name="shipment_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipment#</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> -->
        <actionsColumn name="shipment_id" class="Ecom\Ecomexpress\Ui\Renderer\Shipmentid">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">awb_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipment#</item>
                </item>
            </argument>     
        </actionsColumn>
<!--          <column name="state">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> -->
        <column name="state" class="Ecom\Ecomexpress\Ui\Renderer\Awbstatus">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        
        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
         </column>
<!--          <column name="orderid">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order#</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> -->
        <actionsColumn name="orderid" class="Ecom\Ecomexpress\Ui\Renderer\Orderid">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">orderid</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order#</item>
                </item>
            </argument>     
        </actionsColumn>
         <column name="awb_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">AWB Type</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="distributor_code" class="Ecom\Ecomexpress\Ui\Renderer\Distributorcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">  </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Distributor Code</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="updated_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated At</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="reverse_pickup_generated">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reverse Pickup Generated</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="in_used">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">In Used</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns> 
</listing>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Basically order can be display in a grid on the basis of seller-id.You mean the orders created by seller  ?

Comment: No, Order assigned to the seller after order success from the frontend.

Comment: You can filter the orders collection by seller code according to the admin user session.

Comment: @SatishDubariya how can I filter order collection. and where I put this?

Comment: please share your collection file code.

Comment: Is it possible to filter grid $dataSource  as defined above code

Comment: You have to override the collection file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php` then you can use the addFieldToFilter method in select query.

Comment: @Msquare, I have added code where getting collection  $dataSource['data']['items']

Comment: @SatishDubariya, Thanks. Same thing I want with the custom grid which is for ecomExpress. And column added by UI component.

Comment: @VinodKumar can you explain in details for ecomExpress?

Comment: I have a grid for AWB number in ecomExpress which have seller_code. I want to display only grid data related by the logged-in seller. The above code is for EcomExpress.

Comment: @SatishDubariya, I have updated the code where I have added column seller_code and when any seller login into admin then related data to that seller_code will be displayed in the grid

Comment: @VinodKumar check my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112769/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-satish-dubariya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code as shown below. **Do not forget to override this file**.
`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php`

```
protected $authSession;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ...
}

protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    /** admin user filter start **/
    $adminUser = $this->authSession->getUser();
    if ($adminUser->getId()) {
        $adminUserName = $adminUser->getUsername();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('seller_code', ['eq' => $adminUserName]);
    }
    /** end **/
    $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
    foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
        $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

@VinodKumar - For ecomExpress Grid, you have to find your collection file and add `_initSelect` function in that file like below:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    /** admin user filter start **/
    $adminUser = $this->authSession->getUser();
    if ($adminUser->getId()) {
        $adminUserName = $adminUser->getUsername();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('seller_code', ['eq' => $adminUserName]);
    }
    /** end **/
  
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is working fine for Order grid

Comment: If my answer is useful, you can upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for a custom grid ecomExpress which column added by UI Component

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: updated code in question

Comment: distributor_code or seller_id is the same as the admin User.

Comment: can you share your di,xml file code where you have defined the collection model for data source show_ecomexpress_awb_listing_data_source?

Comment: I didn't find this data source  show_ecomexpress_awb_listing_data_source except this file.

Comment: This is the collection file code:  
<?php


namespace Ecom\Ecomexpress\Model\ResourceModel\Awb;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {
 public function _construct() {
  $this->_init ( 'Ecom\Ecomexpress\Model\Awb', 'Ecom\Ecomexpress\Model\ResourceModel\Awb' );
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This code into your collection file**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

/**
 * Order grid collection
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $authSession;
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
     * @param EventManager $eventManager
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $resourceModel
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    ) {
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $tableDescription = $this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->getMainTable());
        foreach ($tableDescription as $columnInfo) {
            $this->addFilterToMap($columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME'], 'main_table.' . $columnInfo['COLUMN_NAME']);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function _beforeLoad()
    {
        $log_admin = $this->authSession->getUser()->getUserId()
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('seller_code', $log_admin);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine for order grid. I am also looking for custom grid which column added by UI Component